# CSS draw down arrow for email (mail.google.com issues)

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

In my email html template I need this arrow [image]

- my first attempt was http://jsfiddle.net/b0vryojq/ but gmail online client doesn't make deal with `position`
- so I moved it to http://jsfiddle.net/b0vryojq/2/ (I need it aligned to center) but still have troubles when resizing client

Don't offer use embedded image, it must be css ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant guarantee that margin auto will work in Google mail but you can try adding a container div

```
<tr>
    <td>
         <div class="container">
            <div class="top"></div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width:48px;
    margin:auto;
}

.top{
    margin-left: 17.5px;
    min-height:24px;
    background:#bedfd0;
    width: 16px;
}

.bottom{                        
    border:solid transparent;  
    border-width:26px;
    border-top:31px solid #bedfd0;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Jsfiddle update here: http://jsfiddle.net/b0vryojq/6/

Answer (score 1):

As shown in this [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x1a96qtm/) you can make use of CSS `calc()` to get around this

```css
.div1 {
    min-height:24px;
    background:#bedfd0;
    width: 16px;
    margin-left:calc(50% + 8px);
}
.div2 {
    border:solid transparent;
    min-height:0;
    width:0;
    border-width:26px;
    border-top:31px solid #bedfd0;
    margin-left:calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div2"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks, but seems gmail ignores negative margin `margin-left:calc(50% - 10px);`

Comment: the value won't be negative - *not until the total width of the email viewport is less than `20px` * - this function should return positive value because it means, calculate 50% of the total width and subtract 10px of it

Comment: I've sent email with your css - first `calc` was rendered, but second doesn't :\